# Sequelize unique custom message

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, unique, sequelize-typescript

When I try to define a custom message, the default message `Validation error` still appears.

The `unique` property accepts either a boolean or an `object` whit properties `name` and `msg`. What does `name` mean? Why don't I see the message in `msg`?

```
sequelize: 6.16.1
```

Thank you

```
   idcustomer: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: {
        name: 'idcustomer',
        msg: 'idcustomer duplicate',
      },
      validate: {
        notEmpty: {
          msg: RequiredFieldMessage('Id Customer'),
        },
      },
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unique` is a constraint and makes sense in DB unlike `validate` option that is used by Sequelize only.
See [validations and constraints](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/validations-and-constraints.html#difference-between-validations-and-constraints)

I suppose `name` and `msg` is for cases when a DB will throw SequlizeUqniueConstraint error.